# Leaflet : Multiple Markers on dragend function not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Variable:

```
var marker = [];
var i;

constructor(map) {
    this.map2 = L.map(map); 

    this.polygon_layer = {};
    this.default_polygon = [
        [3.1377736432253345, 101.56585693359375],
        [2.929326028392636, 101.6619873046875],
        [3.03629758922721, 101.89544677734375],
        [3.247466393872138, 101.8048095703125],
        [3.1377736432253345, 101.56585693359375]
    ];
    this.markers = {};
    this.marker ={};

}
```

Main flow here

```
createMarkers(){
    i=0;
    this.default_polygon.forEach(x =>
        marker[i] = this.setMarker(x)
    )        
}
```

i set on `dragend` function on each marker to show coordinates for each marker. But eventually other markers coordinates shown after drag are same with the last marker created. When the last marker moves , all markers followed the last marker coordinates. Sorry for my broken english.

```
setMarker(coord){
    this.marker = L.marker(coord,{draggable: true})
    .on('dragend', function() {
        var coord = String(this.marker.getLatLng()).split(',');
        var lat = coord[0].split('(');
        var lng = coord[1].split(')');
        this.marker.bindPopup("Moved to: " + lat[1] + ", " + lng[0] + ".");

        var newCoord = [parseFloat(lng[0]),parseFloat(lat[1])]
        console.log(newCoord)

    },this)
    .addTo(this.map2);

    i++

    return this.marker;
}
```

console log of coordinates

[image]

Any help is appreciate ! Wish to get know where there is a mistake...

Comment: What is your question, I don't understand it? And don't get latlng with split, use: `this.marker.getLatLng().lat` or `this.marker.getLatLng().lng`

Comment: Noted , but those just to convert into string and add `( )` to those coordinates for `.bindPopup()` use. My question is the on `dragend` function works only on 1 marker. Other markers do not follow its own correct coordinates after dragging

Comment: try to replace `this.marker = L.marker` with `var marker = L.marker`. Can you pls create a example on jsfiddle?

Comment: `this.marker.getLatLng().lat or this.marker.getLatLng().lng` this would get the latlng , i found the problem is the `this.marker.bindPopup` doesnt work on all markers. But the coordinates can be found using `marker.getLatLng()`. Thanks @FalkeDesign

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?